# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, url, attributes

I use python and this is my code

```
        myUser = 'username'
        myServer = 'http://api.url.net', "{\"orga\":\"monorga\",\"coupon\":\"moncoupon\"}"
        myPass = 'pass'
        authString = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (myUser, myPass))
        headers = {'Authorization':"Basic %s" % authString}
        req = urllib2.Request(myServer, None, headers)
        openedUrl = urllib2.urlopen(req)

url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Please help me

Comment: What is your first line doing? Is that supposed to be one long string? It is currently creating a `tuple` of two elements, and storing them in `url`

Comment: What you want to do and whats your excepted result?

Comment: Yes, you created a tuple, by creating two string values with a comma in between. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Please provide at least a __working__ example, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `url` isn't assigned in your example.

Comment: I now, url is not affected and i have that error ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `url = 'https://api.url.net', "{\"orga\":\"monorga\",\"coupon\":\"moncoupon\"}"`, basically you're just creating a `tuple` of two elements (`'https://api.url.net'` and `"{\"orga\":\"monorga\",\"coupon\":\"moncoupon\"}"`), and assigning a reference to this tuple to the `url` variable. This is due to the fact that, in python, there is not always the need to write the parenthesis of a tuple: `a = 1, 2` for example.

Thus, `url` is now a tuple. Also, a tuple does not have a `strip` method, so you can't call `url.strip`.

To call `strip` on `url`, you must first convert it to a string.

Comment: @Zehef I don't know what you want really, if you just want to concatenate the two elements of the tuple, just do `url_string = ''.join[e for e in url]` or, easier, `url_string = url[0] + url[1]`. Also notice that, in your case, `strip` is useless: it removes trailing and leading whitespaces, but you have none...

Comment: I want convert ruby request URL_COUPON, {'coupon' => coupon, 'organization' => @organisation} in python request

Answer (score 2):

I found this question whilst encountering this error message.

In my case, the problem was that I had an errant trailing comma on a line declaring a string, like so:

`x = "my string",`

x is therefore, I think quite strangely, a tuple of length one. First and only element is `"my string"`.

This strikes me as an easy and confusing error to make, so I thought I'd put this answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your output is a tuple:

```
url = 'https://api.url.net', "{\"orga\":\"monorga\",\"coupon\":\"moncoupon\"}"
```

and tuple object has no attribute 'strip'.
You can solve this problem with this method:

```
url = url[0] + url[1]
```